# Passing args from Instance Method to function using scipy optimize

Tags: python, scipy, instance, self, args

I have a class object like this with instance methods.

```
class Neural:
    def __init__(self, params, X, y, lambda1):
        ---
    def costFunction(self):
        ---
        return J
    def backPropogate(self):
        ---
        return grad_back
```

I am trying to call the functions using scipy.optimize.minimize

```
result = opt.minimize(Neural(params_init, X, y, 1).costFunction(), x0=params_init, method='CG',
                     jac=Neural(params_init, X, y, 1).backPropogate())
```

I keep on getting

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

I have tried not calling the function with (), but I just get (this seems to me most correct):

> **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lambda1'

I have tried using args like this:

```
result = opt.minimize(Neural.costFunction, x0=params_init, args=(X, y, 1), method='CG',
                     jac=Neural.backPropogate)
```

but the args parameter is recognized for the function of the class, not the object itself. If I call the functions instead like this Neural.costFunction(), I get

> missing positional requirement "self"

Answer (score 0):

The function you give to `minimize` should take `x`, a variable shaped like `x0`, and the values that you pass via the `args`.  `minimize` steps through various `x` as it searches, but passes the same `*args` each time.

If you change class to:

```
class Neural:
    def __init__(self, X, y, lambda1):
        ---
    def costFunction(self, params):
        ---
        return J
```

you should be able use it as:

```
myobj = Neural(X, y, 1)
opt.minimize(myobj.costFunction, x0=params_init, method='CG',jac=myobj.backPropogate)
```

`backPropogate` needs a similar adjustment.

I'd test it with a call like

```
Neural(X, y, 1).costFunction(params_init)
```

To use `args,`costFunction`needs to accept`X, y, lambda1`, eg:

```
....
def costFunction(self, params, X, y, lambda1):
```

and is created with `Neural().costFunction`.

Comment: changed costFunction to accept params instead of __init__
and executed
opt.minimize(Neural(X, y, 1).costFunction, x0=params_init, method='CG',
                     jac=Neural(X, y, 1).backPropogate())
like you recommended (except the params_init because that's no longer an arg for Neural), it still returns the ambiguity error

Comment: I don't think the ambiguity error has anything to do with how you pass arguments.  To address that you need to tell us what code raises that error (`traceback`).  Most likely you are using a boolean array (or array comparison) in a scalar context like an `if` statement.  But, back to argument passing, why did you put `()` on `backpogate`?  Doesn't the documentation say that `jac` is supposed to be a callable?

Comment: similar adjustment meaning adding "params" as a function parameter? opt.minimize(myobj.costFunction, x0=params_init, method='CG',jac=myobj.backPropogate) still doesn't work
besides, I need params in Neural since other variables are defined by it

Comment: I assume `params` is the array that is being optimized, starting some initial `x0` value.  It will change with each call to `costFunction` and `backPropogate`.  You could pass `params_init` to `Neural.__init__` if needed.  It may help to step back and practice using `minimize` with simpler functions, so you have a clearer idea of what it expects.  Using class methods seems to be confusing you.

Comment: can you try to explain why `opt.minimize(Neural(params_init, X, y, 1).costFunction, x0=params_init, method='CG', jac=Neural(params_init, X, y, 1).backPropogate)` gives me backPropogate() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (self and x0)? Is there no one way to use x0 for `Neural.__init__`? All the parameters are processed through `Neural.__init__` and passed as variables to the functions. I'm using class methods mainly to avoid having to redefine variables. Having params as a parameter of the functions kind of defeats that